# How to set JMS message acknowledgement type when using Camel's ProducerTemplate

Tags: jms, message, apache-camel

I am using the camel context and creating from it the producer/consumer templates, for using the jms communication.
Can you please tell me which is the proper method to set the type of message acknowledgment in this situation?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be set on the jmsconfiguration bean if you are using one for the component. I prefer that.

It can be set on the endpoint url too

```
template.send("activemq:queue:...?acknowledgementModeName=..);
```